# How to "replace" a relationship in Neo4j using Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a set of relationships that I want to "replace", i.e. create a new one then delete the old one since relationships are immutable.

I originally assumed this:

```
MATCH paths=()-[:BRANCH]-()
FOREACH (old in relationships(paths) |
    WITH startNode(old) as n1, endNode(old) as n2
    MERGE (n1)-[new:CONTAINS]-(n2)
    SET new = old
    DELETE r
)
```

but the `WITH` keyword is not allowed and have to be able to figure out how to assign local variables to the start and end nodes.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use FOREACH again to hack that WITH, for example:

```
FOREACH (n1 in [startNode(old)]| ... // you now have an identifier n1 referring to startNode(old)
```

If this is just a length 1 path, I'm not sure I see the value of doing it this way, though. Can't you just do:

```
MATCH (n1)-[old:BRANCH]->(n2) 
CREATE (n1)-[new:CONTAINS]->(n2) 
DELETE old
```

Comment: Ah great, thank you. The latter is what I need at the moment, but will explore the former. I tend to forget the set-like nature of these operations.